# Android how to create apk file using ant script

Tags: android, ant, apk

anybody tell me, building apk using ant script

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the android developers documentation in the [Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html) topic. Assumed you created your project with the `android` tool it should be:

```
ant release
```

The documentation also describes the "eclipse with ADT" way

If you first set up the project with eclipse than try to create a new temp project with the [android create project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#CreatingAProject) command line command and take the `build.xml` (and `build.properties` + `local.properties`) from the new project for your existing one.

Answer (score 1):

http://androidyou.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-project-ant-build-and-put.html

add one target to get the version, using the regular expression to extract it from the manifest.xml

then add this as a dependency to the release target

Comment: You should add some more of the details in the link to your answer. Link only answers can eventually go bad